# Can't click a button in WebView via Javascript in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I'm creating an Android app with WebView to show a webpage. I want to link a button in my app's layout (triggerButton) to activate a button (btn1) on the webpage when pressed. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to make this work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWeb;
    Button triggerButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWeb = findViewById(R.id.myWeb);
        myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWeb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWeb.loadUrl("myUrl");

        myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                triggerButton = findViewById(R.id.triggerButton);
                triggerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('btn1').style.backgroundColor = 'red';", null); //this works
                        view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('btn1').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));", null); //this doesnt work
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I can change the style of btn1 (background color) with this command:

```
view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('btn1').style.backgroundColor = 'red';", null);
```

but I can't seem to press the button with the same format

```
view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('btn1').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));", null);
```

At first I tested ".click()" in Chrome console, didn't work. With ChatGPT's help, used "document.getElementById('btn1').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));", which works consistently in the console, but not in my app.

I tried the exact same thing on Stackoverflow.com to click the login button, and it worked flawlessly with the same method I applied in my app. I suspect it might have something to do with the security or privacy settings of the website I'm working with (raspberry pi webiopi).

Comment: When you say that "it doesn't work", can you elaborate on what exactly breaks? Also, it would help to see what javascript bridge interface you defined for the cross communication.

Comment: @tomerpacific Apologies for my limited coding knowledge, I'm not quite sure what a bridge interface is. Full MainActivity.java code is in my post other than it is just a default Empty Activity Android Studio java app where I just added a button in XML and Android INTERNET permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.

Also tested ".click()" in Chrome console, didn't work. With ChatGPT's help, used "document.getElementById("btn").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));", which works consistently in the console, but not in my app.

Comment: @tomerpacific What exactly breaks ; In my code, I can successfully change the button color to red. However, when I attempt to click it using the previously mentioned command, it doesn't work, despite working in Chrome's console. Interestingly, I tested this on Stackoverflow.com to click the login button, and it worked flawlessly with the same method I applied in my app. I suspect it might have something to do with the security or privacy settings of the website I'm working with (raspberry pi webiopi

Comment: Usually a button code is executed not when you press the mouse button but when you release it after pressing. So you send the pressed event but not the release event. If the button triggers JavaScript code wouldn't calling onClick directly be easier?

Comment: @jan - You could expose a method in your javascript code that triggers the click logic of your button. That way, you could invoke that method from your application. [I wrote an article](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-build-cross-origin-communication-bridges-in-ios-and-andriod-7baef82b3f02) about cross communication bridges in Android that can be of help.